# How do we solve a variant of the knapsack problem in which the capacity of the knapsack keeps increasing as we add more items into the knapsack?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, knapsack-problem

Given a set of N objects of positive integer weights {w_i}, how to find the subset of these objects that maximizes

> **summation(x_i*(log w_i))**   *(i goes from 1 to N)*
>
> such that **summation(x_i*w_i) < 10000*sqrt(k)** *(i goes from 1 to N)*
>
> where **k** is the number of items selected and
>
> x_i = 1 if w_i is used and
>
> x_i = 0 if w_i is not used

In LaTeX:

[image]

Note that weights w_i are positive integers,so log(w_i) is also positive.
For this specific problem, N = 1000.

One approach that I tried was to solve the exact-k knapsack problem for each value of k. But it takes too long to run the program as k goes from 1 to 1000.
Is there some way that we can find a solution for k and then use that to find the solution for k+1 ?

Comment: Your description is different from the LaTex model. You take the log of x[i] (which is heroic given that x[i] can be zero). The model looks nonlinear (square root of the number of selected items). May be an MINLP solver is a start.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I've corrected it now.

Comment: This looks like a convex problem. I am not completely sure this can be formulated as a MISOCP (second order cone) problem. 

However, global solvers like **Couenne** and **Baron** do actually do a good job on this. Solved with 1000 items (random data) in a few seconds. **Bonmin** can also work (use the B-OA algorithm). Pure branch&bound methods seem not as good for this problem.

Comment: This can actually be formulated as a MISOCP or convex MIQCP. That would allow you to use some additional high-performance solvers such as **Cplex** and **Gurobi**.

Comment: Your LaTeX says log_100; did you mean log_10?